# makefile: zip *.doc with 7z.exe and only in numeric folders

Tags: makefile

I need help creating a makefile. I  want to go through only **numeric** folders Folder names that contain letters must be ignored.

```
    cd $(FOLDER); \     #is not numeric
    for dir in `ls -1`; do \     # only numeric     
      ......
```

My second question: How can I zips all .doc for which yet no .zip was created?

thank you in advance
pet

Comment: This isn't so much a makefile question but a shell question. for the first question, use something like `[0-9]*` instead of `\`ls -1\``. For the second one, it will depend on the naming convention, but something like: `for f in *.doc ; do if [ ! -e $f.zip ] ; then zip $f ; fi ; done`

Comment: I would suggest you let Make handle the iteration; if you're just going to embed a shell script inside a makefile, why use Make at all? And one question per Question, please.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The numeric folder I have done well.